# Catch the first time when '1' comes up in a list of boolean variables - Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am new to Linear Programming. Say, I have a list of boolean variables `x[i]`, `i` ranging from 0 till 5. Now, I want to identify the first occurence where the any of the 5 boolean variables turn to be 1. So for instance, post the solve, `x` resolves to [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], then I want another boolean variable `y[i]`, which will report : [0, 1, 0, 0, 0].

I tried something, but running into problems since I cannot access the values of `x` until the solve happens.

Comment: Which library are you using to perform the solve? Since this is a post-processing step, it's not necessary or desirable to represent `y` as an actual linear programming variable. Also: i from 0 to 5 is only 5 variables if 5 is an exclusive bound.

Comment: I am using pyomo. It is not a post-processing step. I want to establish a relationship between x and y during the solve : whenever first occurence of `1` comes say, in index 2, then I want at index 2, y should also be `1`. I will use `y` further in my optimization program. Below answer actually suffices my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following constraints which will maintain the desired relation between `x` and `y` variables:

```
sum(i, y[i]) <= 1 ; for 0 <= i <= 4
y_i <= x_i ; for 0 <= i <= 4
sum(i, y[i]) >= x_j ; for 0 <= j <= 4, i will range from 0 till j
```

*sorry, not very comfortable in using latex symbols in stackoverflow*

Below is implementation in Google-OR-tool's linear solver.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

s = pywraplp.Solver("", pywraplp.Solver.SCIP_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)

x = {i: s.BoolVar("") for i in range(5)}
y = {i: s.BoolVar("") for i in range(5)}

# forcing second and fourth variable to be 1
s.Add(x[1] + x[3] == 2)
# all remaining are forced to be zero
s.Add(sum(x[i] for i in range(5)) == 2)

# below are the 3 constraints that were listed above:
# 1.
s.Add(sum(y[i] for i in range(5)) <= 1)

# 2.
for i in range(5):
    s.Add(y[i] <= x[i])

# 3.
for j in range(5):
    s.Add(sum(y[i] for i in range(j + 1)) >= x[j])

s.Solve()
{i: x[i].SolutionValue() for i in range(5)}
#{0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 0.0}

{i: y[i].SolutionValue() for i in range(5)}
#{0: 0.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 0.0, 3: -0.0, 4: 0.0}
```